# Is there a way to check how much a file can be compressed without actually compressing it?

Tags: linux, compression

I have a large (80GB) virtual drive file which I want to compress but, before I do, I want to see how compressible it actually is, before embarking on creating another (potentially) big file (if it turns out that the data cannot be compressed much).

Is there a way to do this? i.e. analysing an existing set of data to see whether there is much room for compression without actually writing an output file?

Comment: "without actually compressing" means "without creating a file" or "without spending CPU cycles"?

Comment: Without creating a file, yes. Have clarified the question, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Note (regarding your original question): `tar` does not compress.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any compressing tool that can write to stdout can be used. Just pipe it to `wc -c`. Example:

```
gzip -c -9 < bigfile | wc -c
```

Note the tool does its job and stresses your CPU regardless of where the output goes.

Comment: I would add `pv bigfile | gzip | wc -c` or even `pv -cN raw bigfile | gzip | pv -cN zipped | wc -c` if you want a progress output.

Comment: So there is no way to just analyse the data to be compressed, to see by how much it would be compressed, without actually compressing it, right? Because if I understand correctly what is going on here (because maybe I'm not) then it is actually compressing the data to figure out how big the result is?

Comment: @mydoghasworms I guess some heuristics that work in some cases are possible; but I can't say I've seen a tool that works this way.

Comment: Thanks, in that case I will accept your answer. I started the process with @grawity 's recommendation to use pv for the progress output. Will still take in excess of half an hour to find how much this 80GB file can be compressed. In terms of time and energy costs vs storage costs, it's probably more worth it to copy the file as is :-) It's an interesting exercise anyway, so thanks for the answer!

Comment: @grawity Is there a way to produce a running update from `wc` to tell you how big the result is so far while this is running? (I am assuming, perhaps wrongly, that the process results are being streamed through the pipe - as opposed to waiting for the preceding task to finish - but so far I don't notice any increase in memory usage).

Comment: @mydoghasworms This is what the second `pv` is for.

Comment: Ah, never mind, the answer was there on the command line, staring me in the face!

Comment: Thanks, sorry, only noticed that now! I was looking only at the bar and didn't notice the size.